# How to measure cache performance of zfs with cache drive

Tags: caching, zfs

I am trying to compare different filesystems, most with cache/tiered storage features, but so far it does not seem to work as it should. (btw, I know this might the wrong site, but when I searched for zfs, most SE results were on stackoverflow, so it seemed good to ask here)

When testing zfs, I created a single pool, with a main drive/partition and another drive (ssd) added as a cache. The main drive/partition was around 200 GB, the ssd 120 GB. This showed up correctly in zpool.

Then I ran phoronix test suite with iozone, or iozone separately. After some initial unfamiliarity, I settled on `phoronix-test-suite run-default  pts/iozone` which I than ran on just a hdd, just an ssd and an hdd partition with ssd as a cache. And on two laptops which have ssds for comparisons. In the test with zfs + cache, there was virtually no difference to using just an hdd. It was really really slow. And I made sure to set the working directory to the zpool and verified that the temp file was created there and also checked zpool iostat to make sure that the pool was working.
Now, while I might have suspected lower results, I would hope that the speeds should at least be somewhat slower, especially with an 'easy' test such as this, which just does 3 runs of reading 1 MB records from an 8 GB file, and then 3 runs of writing 1 MB records from an 8 GB file.

Now, maybe because of the way zfs cache and similar ones work - they cannot be captured by such a simple test - but then, which would be a good test to capture the benefit of the cache? However, as the test file fits on the cache ssd easily, why it is not written there first and transferred back to the hdd in the background?

The zpool looks like this:

```
pool: ztest
state: ONLINE
scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    ztest       ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdb7      ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      sdc       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `zpool status` so we can see the setup? It sounds like you either didn't configure your pool correctly, or the test is not testing what you expected, and it'd be nice to make sure it's not the former.

Comment: I added the pool description. This was created with `zpool create ztest /dev/sdb7 cache /dev/sdc` based on docs I found. After reading some more it seems that cache may only be a read cache (though this still wouldn't explain terrible read performance) and for write cache a zil would be necessary in addition. But on some of the same pages it was also said that a ZIL would only make sense for big storage volumes or huge servers/specific workloads. Which seems strange, as in other cases, people describe zfs as usable for almost everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my guesses of what the mismatch in expectation / reality is:

**For the read benchmark (3 runs of reading 1 MB records from an 8 GB file)**

The ZFS cache device (commonly called the "L2ARC") gets populated when a block is written or read. From your description, I'm guessing that the benchmark writes the file once, then reads it sequentially 3 times. I would expect the L2ARC to make a copy of the blocks on your cache device during the first write, or at the very least when you first read the data. (Although, note that the L2ARC does not yet persist across reboots because the map of what's on disk is only stored in memory -- kind of a silly limitation but probably not what's affecting your test.)

Are you using `zfs set secondarycache=all` to cache all data blocks, as opposed to just `metadata` blocks? (Just to disambiguate / explain the naming, the `primarycache` property has similar settings for the in-RAM cache, aka the "ARC".)

To check if the L2ARC is being used during your benchmark, you can look at [`arcstat`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/blob/master/cmd/arcstat/arcstat.py) data -- the stats you'll be interested in are:

```
"l2hits":     [6, 1000, "L2ARC hits per second"],
"l2miss":     [6, 1000, "L2ARC misses per second"],
```

With the benchmark you described, I would expect to see a very high hit rate (assuming your SSD is >8GB).

**For the write benchmark (3 runs of writing 1 MB records from an 8 GB file)**

This will only be helped if you also add an SSD `log` device (commonly called the "ZIL" like you mentioned in one of the comments). I'd split your SSD into two partitions: one very small to use as the ZIL (only has to store enough data to cache ~10s of writes assuming you haven't tuned the filesystem), and one using the rest of the drive as an L2ARC.

To address the advice you found about not using a ZIL unless you have a big beefy server, I don't think there's any reason not to use a ZIL on a small system. I guess it ties up a little extra SSD that could have been used for a read cache, but it doesn't use extra RAM or a noticeable amount of additional CPU, so effectively it should speed up your write latencies / burst throughput with no adverse side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. The secondarycache is set to all, it says this is the default. I switched from using phoronix-test-suite to running a similar benchmark manually, as it allows for easier switching to only run read and making sure that the same file is used. This made results more predictable, and they improved in subsequent runs but still more in line with hdd performance (68.5 MBytes/s on read). This seems to be confirmed by the fact that `arcstat -f l2hits,l2miss` didn't seem to work at all during read only runs, only showing 1-5 and mostly zero during the original write/read.

Comment: Any ideas for that? Didn't test with ZIL yet.

Comment: I read some more details on the L2ARC, and apparently it’s not as deterministic as I thought. (See [here](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2008-07-22/zfs-l2arc.html) for details from the original author.) It sounds like perhaps you just need to have the system running, reading these blocks for a bit longer, to see the benefit. In that article it also mentions that sequential workloads don’t benefit from the L2ARC; I read through the code though and didn’t see any provisions about that. Perhaps that got torn out, I’m not sure.

Comment: Mmmh, I can copy a system over, or iozone also has the possibility to do random read/write (from the same file) over a period of time so maybe that could be an option. From when do you think does something count as sequential? I read in bcache docs (related as it is about caching) that they by default treat sequential (which I assume means big, continuous) writes differently, but depending on the size this can be disabled or doesn't make sense, as when I have a 120 GB or more ssd (for say, a 2-4TB hdd) then why shouldn't that 8GB file be cached before it gets transferred to hdd?

Comment: Some more info: Here https://pthree.org/2013/04/19/zfs-administration-appendix-a-visualizing-the-zfs-intent-log/ the ZIL is described more as a backup, that just moves the ZIL from the hdd/ram to the SSD but is in essence just a backup, so that it is just used if the system is interrupted and data is not written to the hdd yet, but otherwise never used.

Comment: My own ongoing test are even weirder - I now made a new pool cache and zil, starting by copying a working linux onto it and then see how that works. While copying, I monitor with `iostat` and so it seems the ZIL is not used, not even for backup. Whereas the cache is shown to be slowly filling. This seems weird, as no files should be accessed. For copying, I used rsync, could it be that it reads files as confirmation, and that is why they are moved to cache? Screenshot of iostat: https://imgur.com/a/qAPzFSC (also I'll accept your answer for now but I see it as an ongoing investigation)

Comment: The article I linked above touched on the cache behavior you’re seeing — the L2ARC is filled by asynchronously copying stuff from the ARC to the SSD. All writes end up in the ARC if there’s space (because why not use that RAM if you have it?) so it’s just gradually caching stuff that’s been written recently. For the stuff you said about the ZIL, I think the “backup” analogy is a little wrong. It’s not a write journal that is required for correctness (like i.e. ext4 would have) — it’s the way to commit synchronous writes with low latency, because the normal write path is asynchronous.

Comment: To explain why the ZIL isn’t being used, rsync may not be issuing sync writes to ZFS, so ZFS is choosing to use the normal async write path. This is more efficient from its perspective, because it doesn’t have to write the data twice (once to the ZIL and once to the main pool).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I didn't mean backup as 'write journal' but based on the description stuff is first written to the ZIL (independent of RAM or SSD based) and then only removed from there once written to the backing device. Regarding ZIL not being used, I saw this also with iozone and fio benchmarks. So far it seems like bcache or bcachefs is much more relevant to my use case. Especially as also on first boot zfs decided to do a scrub for whatever reason so booting took forever (and I didn't see that because of no framebuffer console for unrelated reasons).

Comment: Is there some benchmark or workload where you know that it is suited to zfs and will use both cache and ZIL?